# Imaging Cost Data and Procedure Costs

Tags: data-request, medical, prices

I am looking for average charge or cost data for the following procedures for outpatient imaging centers. Arthroscopic surgery, cataract, colonoscopy, CT scan, ekg, X-Ray. Ultrasound, mri, pet scan, mammogram, mammography, kidney stone removal, hernia repair, endoscopy, EKG, tonsillectomy and ear tube placement, knee surgery.  Is there any database that shows the average costs by facility, city or state levels?

Comment: When you say "state", are you talking about a particular country of the globe?

Answer (score 3):

Medicare has a public dataset that may provide the information you are looking for:

> **Medicare Provider Utilization and Payment Data: Physician and Other**
>   Supplier
>
> As part of the Obama Administration’s efforts to make our healthcare
>   system more transparent, affordable, and accountable, the Centers for
>   Medicare & Medicaid Services (CMS) has prepared a public data set, the
>   Medicare Provider Utilization and Payment Data: Physician and Other
>   Supplier Public Use File (Physician and Other Supplier PUF), with
>   information on services and procedures provided to Medicare
>   beneficiaries by physicians and other healthcare professionals.  The
>   Physician and Other Supplier PUF contains information on utilization,
>   payment (allowed amount and Medicare payment), and submitted charges
>   organized by National Provider Identifier (NPI), Healthcare Common
>   Procedure Coding System (HCPCS) code, and place of service. This PUF
>   is based on information from CMS’s National Claims History Standard
>   Analytic Files. The data in the Physician and Other Supplier PUF
>   covers calendar year 2012 and contains 100% final-action
>   physician/supplier Part B non-institutional line items for the
>   Medicare fee-for-service population.

http://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Medicare-Provider-Charge-Data/Physician-and-Other-Supplier.html

Comment: 1.7GB uncompressed CSV, more than 9 million records